# Blender3d Baking Animation Problem

Tags: animation, armature, export, baking, unity

I have 2 Armature in my scene.The first one is for my rigged rifle,and second one is my arms, also i'm animated it(i'm baked animation).When i import to unity3d my model,That's what i see in animation tab [image]

There is a lot of animation clips and no ones is my animation.

Comment: If you want only one animation in an export just disable the "All Actions" and the "NLA strips" options in the export menu.

Comment: Thank you It works,but if my rifle had more than one animation,what i should do then ?

Comment: Unity supports multiple animations strip, but we can't  figured out how it really works. Also if you want animating with IK or other constraits in Blender you can export it only with the mentioned method. If we need multiple animations, we cluster them into one long strip in Blender then cut them apart in Unity. It's not too elegant but works fine.